# MYSQL Group if parent field is not empty

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Is there a way to GROUP row's together if the parent is not empty

I will explain the database first:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
ID    |    NAME    |       date       |    PARENT ID
-----------------------------------------------------
1    | John Doe   |    2018-01-12    |
2    | Doe John   |    2018-01-12    |    
3    | Doe John   |    2018-02-12    |        2
4    | Doe John   |    2018-03-22    |        2
```

Now what i want is to get a list like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
ID    |    NAME    |           date          |    PARENT ID
-------------------------------------------------------------
1    | John Doe    |       2018-01-12        |
2    | Doe John    | 2018-01-12 / 2018-03-22 |
```

I have try things like:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(parentID)
FROM names
GROUP BY parentID;
```

But then is the result only those with a parentID, and I want to show the ones without parentID and group those with a parentID to ID

Comment: You'd need to explain better, this looks more like a need for a WHERE clause on parent_id IS NULL than a grouping problem...

Comment: Is the entry of the `date` column for the groups `CONCAT(MIN(date), ' / ', MAX(date))`? (+date format...)

Comment: It is not entirely clear, at least not to me, how `date` is being calculated. Does it contain the date of the node along with the dates of its children? If yes, then why is not date `2018-02-12` not included for `Doe John` ?

Comment: `SELECT * .... GROUP BY parentID`  is asking for trouble because it's not a ansi valid group by query meaning the results can be unrelated to the grouped column parentID.  read https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: I have put some example data in it, i need it for an reservation code what im writing. So someone can reservate more dates and I want to combine is it has an parent with the Parent id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to JOIN to table on itself using a `LEFT JOIN`, using the initial table as parents and the joined table as children.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
  users as parents
  LEFT JOIN users as children ON parents.id = children.parent_id
```

A `LEFT JOIN` will keep all rows from the initial table (*parents* in this case) and just add rows from the joined table (*children* in this case) to it, if the join is possible. Ohterwise only `NULL` values will be added.

```
| id |   name     |    date    | parent_id |   id   |    name     |    date    | parent_id |
|  2 |  Doe John  | 2018-01-12 |   (null)  |    3   |   Bill John | 2018-02-12 |     2     |
|  2 |  Doe John  | 2018-01-12 |   (null)  |    4   |   Elmo John | 2018-03-22 |     2     |
|  1 |  John Doe  | 2018-01-12 |   (null)  | (null) |    (null)   |   (null)   |   (null)  |
|  3 |  Bill John | 2018-02-12 |     2     | (null) |    (null)   |   (null)   |   (null)  |
|  4 |  Elmo John | 2018-03-22 |     2     | (null) |    (null)   |   (null)   |   (null)  |
```

If that is done, there will be exactly one row for each *parent* without *children* and as many rows for each *parent* and *child*, as *children* for that *parent* are present.

Because of that, a `GROUP BY` on the `parents.id` column can be used, because the *parent* is equal for each *child* with the same *parent* and a row exists for each *parent* without *children*. To filter those people from the *parents*, who are children instead of parents, the `WHERE` clause `parents.parent_id IS NULL` can be added.

```
SELECT
    parents.id
FROM
  users as parents
  LEFT JOIN users as children ON parents.id = children.parent_id
WHERE
  parents.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
  parents.id
```

To get the `date` as you want it, you then have to use the aggregate functions [`MIN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) and [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) to calculate the start and end date of the date interval.

The function [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is necessary, because you might have `NULL` values due to the `LEFT JOIN`. It will output the first provided parameter, that is not `NULL`. In this example, the result of `CONCAT` is `NULL`, if `children.date` and therefore `MIN(children.date)` and therefore [`LEAST(...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) returns `NULL`. In that case the second value `paprents.id` will be used.

```
SELECT
  parents.id,
  parents.name,
  COALESCE(
    CONCAT(
      LEAST(parents.date, MIN(children.date)), 
      ' / ', 
      GREATEST(parents.date, MAX(children.date))
    ), 
    parents.date
  ) as 'date'
FROM
  users as parents
  LEFT JOIN users as children ON parents.id = children.parent_id
WHERE
  parents.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
  parents.id,
  parents.name, -- Just added for output without aggregation
  parents.date -- Just added for output without aggregation
```

[Running example on sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5d76/44/0)

Answer (score 2):

You could use group by based on ifnull when parentID is null  use ID

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(parentID)
FROM names
GROUP BY ifnull(parentID, ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(dates.id), MAX(dates.name), MAX(dates.date), MAX(a.date)
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN dates a ON a.parentID = dates.id
WHERE dates.parentID IS NULL GROUP BY a.parentID;
```

The problem you are having is that you need a way to join the data from the lines that have the parentID corresponding to the ID of a line. Using this query we filter lines to show only the ones without a parentID and then grab all lines that have parentID equal to the ID of the current line. Using max ensures correct usage with group by and shows what seems to be asked in your example.